# Cassandra select with clustering key range that might not have primary key

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Sorry the title might/might not give exact description of what i intended.

Here is the problem. I need to select data based on date ranges and most of our queries have 'id' field that is used in our queries.

So, i have created data model with the id as primary key, and date as clustering key.

Essentially like below(i am just using fake/sample statements as i cannot give actual details).

```
create table tab1(
    id text, 
    col1 text, 
    ... coln text, 
    rec_date date, 
    rec_time timestamp, 
    PRIMARY KEY((id),rec_date,rec_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY rec_date DESC, rec_time DESC;
```

It works for most of the queries and worked fine.

However, i was trying to optimize below scenario.

> -> All the records that are greater than the date **abcd-xy-kl**

Which one of the below approaches would be good for me.? Or any thing better than these two.?

**1) very basic or simple approach. Use the query:**

```
select * from tab1 where id > '0' AND rec_date > 'abcd-xy-kl'
```

Every record will be essentially greater than '0'. It might still do full table scan.

**2) Create secondary index on rec_date and simply use the query:**

```
select * from tab1 where rec_date > 'abcd-xy-kl'
```

Also, one key thing is i am using spark and using cassandraSqlContext.sql to get the dataframe.

So, considering all the above details, which approach would be better.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of filtering with id as in your first example. The following should work and would be better approach from my perspective:

```
 select * from tab1 where rec_date > 'abcd-xy-kl' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Note that it won't work without ALLOW FILTERING at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `> 0` for the partition key. It is not supported by Cassandra. Check the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) for more information on the limitations on the `WHERE` part of the queries.

In order to query by your clustering keys efficiently you really need to use a secondary index. Refrain from using the `ALLOW FILTERING` unless you know what you're doing, because it could trigger a "distributed" scan and perform very poorly. Check the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) for more information.